# rails dev production deployment

Tags: ruby-on-rails, capistrano

I have a rails 3 app on my dev machine and I have deployed it to a VPS using Capistrano so the remote customer can take a look and comment etc. I deployed it as a production app even though its got sandbox gateways,no ssl.

The app on the VPS is a spree store and I would like to keep the database updates the customer does so I can roll them out to the production app when we are ready deploy it. This enables the customer to populate his store while we are still tweaking layout etc in dev.

So I kind of have a dev app that's pushed from a local machine to a VPS but I want to keep the data that gets put in the VPS postgres db/ image assets for when it deployed to production.

Is this a good idea ? Is there a way of achieving this in rails/Capistrano/postgresql

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It doesn't matter if the app is in `production`, `dev` or `staging` -- if you need to maintain data consistency, you *could* just hook it up to the same DB:

```
#config/database.yml
same settings for all
```

---

**Recommendation**

To be clear, I would **only** recommend this if you're still in the "pre production" phase (I.E you don't have "real" user data stored). Once you go into production, you'll need to keep your db as efficient as possible; different db's for development & production etc

I would find a cheap DB host (probably [AWS](http://aws.amazon.com/running_databases/)), and let the buyer change anything they want from there. Once this has been finalized, dump the db's so you have dev & production copies to edit